# Select2 initial value not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 4.0.2 for CRUD pages. However, when I try to fill/initialize the `selectbox` in the `edit` page, it doesn't work for some reason. Why doesn't it work? Here's an example of what I have right now, it should be filled with e-mail address test@gmail.com. https://gyazo.com/92a89f5462c36a8c26f4dcd365fb1fb9

It should be something like this, but I don't get it to work: https://gyazo.com/194fa8b11a61736039a5acda763065ae

```
<script>
        token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
        $("#mainuser").select2({
            ajax: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        term: params.term,
                        '_token': token,
                        isnew: 'false',
                        partner_id: {{$partner->id}}
                    };
                },
                url: '/partners/getusers',
                cache: false,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            },
            "language": {
                "noResults": function () {
                    return "Geen gebruikers gevonden.<br> <a href='/klanten/nieuw' class='btn btn-danger'>Maak nieuwe klant</a>";
                }
            },

            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                return markup;
            }
        });
        $("#mainuser").select2('data', {id: 1, text: 'test@gmail.com'});

        // $("#mainuser").select2({...}).select2('data', {...}); doesn't work either...

</script>
```

What I have right now is the selectbox being populated by AJAX as expected, but not being filled (as how it should be in an `edit` page). It should be already filled by the `.select2('data', {id:... text: ...}); part but it's not being filled with this value, as you can see in the video, it's still blank. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187926/how-to-set-selected-value-of-jquery-select2-that-get-data-from-ajax-call) article but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, describe what you expect and what you get.

Comment: You need to run this line `$("#mainuser").select2('data', {id: 1, text: 'test@gmail.com'});` when ajax is done. Because now, you set the value to  `test@gmail.com` but this option is not loaded yet.

Comment: @MoshFeu Tried to use your suggestion but I still can't make it work

Comment: Can you show us the updated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
<script>
        token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
        var select = $('#mainuser');
        select.select2({
            ajax: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        term: params.term,
                        '_token': token,
                        isnew: 'false',
                        partner_id: {{$partner->id}}
                    };
                },
                url: '/partners/getusers',
                cache: true,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            },
            "language": {
                "noResults": function () {
                    return "Geen gebruikers gevonden.<br> <a href='/klanten/nieuw' class='btn btn-danger'>Maak nieuwe klant</a>";
                }
            },

            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                return markup;
            }
        });

        var $option = $('<option selected>Loading...</option>').val(1);
        select.append($option).trigger('change'); // append the option and update Select2

        $.ajax({ // make the request for the selected data object
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/partners/getmainuser',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : { '_token': token, 'isnew' : 'false'},
            headers:
            {
                'X-CSRF-Token': '{{csrf_token()}}'
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            // Here we should have the data object
            $option.text(data.text).val(data.id); // update the text that is displayed (and maybe even the value)
            $option.removeData(); // remove any caching data that might be associated
            select.trigger('change'); // notify JavaScript components of possible changes
        });


</script>
```

Kinda unfortunate that are obligated to initialize with a complete different AJAX call, but this seemed to be the only option.