# The result could not be loaded select2 ajax json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

> I tried this series of code but it doesn't work for me. every time i searched some thing it will give me "The result could not be loaded" 
>   did my missed something here ? Thankyou in advance.

phpfile.php

```
define (DB_USER, "root");
define (DB_PASSWORD, "");
define (DB_DATABASE, "db");
define (DB_HOST, "localhost");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$sql = "SELECT customer_information.CUS_CODE_MX, customer_information.CUS_NAME_MX FROM customer_information WHERE CUS_NAME_MX LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%'
        LIMIT 10"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $json[] = ['id'=>$row['CUS_CODE_MX'], 'text'=>$row['CUS_NAME_MX']];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

index.php

```
<select name="CUSTOMER_ID" id="CUSTOMER_IDGET1" required style="width:100%" class="CUSTOMER_IDGET1 form-control"></select>
```

function.js

```
 $('.CUSTOMER_IDGET1').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an Customer',
        ajax: {
          url: 'ajaxpro.php',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });
```

Comment: in .js function which data you passed

Comment: have you checked Your ajax JSON return which kind of value?

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'jsonp',` from ajax call then check

Comment: Hope This question help to find the solutions [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187926/how-to-set-selected-value-of-jquery-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187926/how-to-set-selected-value-of-jquery-select2)

Comment: it gives me nothing .

Comment: can you share your  code that you will did in **ajaxpro.php**

Comment: $('.CUSTOMER_IDGET1').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an Customer',
        ajax: {
          url: 'ajaxpro.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
     
            };
          },
    
          cache: true
        }
      });

Comment: where should i put this ? $('#inputID').select2('data', {id: 100, a_key: 'Lorem Ipsum'});

Comment: i just give you example forselect2 Okay forget it.
Ma'am when your phpfile.php was exicute?
i just seen **$_GET['q']** in your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147901/discussion-between-jaykumar-gondaliya-and-shermaine-chaingan).