# Yii2: Select2 doesn't send value to controller using jQuery

Tags: jquery, yii2, jquery-select2

I am using a Select2 widget:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_person')->widget(
    \common\widgets\Select2::classname(),
    [
        'items' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Persons::find()->all(), 'id_person', 'name_person'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'idPerson' // For jQuery.
        ]
    ]
)
?>
```

Then I use jQuery to disable it and set a value as I read [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187926/how-to-set-selected-value-of-jquery-select2/35544242):

```
function($) {    
    $("#idPerson").prop("disabled", true)
        .select2('data', {id: 1, a_key: 'John'});
});
```

It properly disabled the Select2 but **the value is not set so the controller doesn't received the value**.

Answer (score 1):

the disabled inputs will not be submitted.
check this: [values of disabled inputs will not be submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted).
Maybe you can use "readonly" instead of disabling the input: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#settings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `kartik-v\select2` widget then you need to know that it is using `Version 4.0` of the plugin select2.

For the versions, `>=4.0` its made simpler and you need to set options as selected using `.val()` and use `.trigger()` to actually make the options change visible, you need to look at 2 things that you can trigger the `change` or `change.select2`

- `change` Causes all attached change events to trigger, including select2.
- `change.select2` Causes only `select2` `change` event to trigger.

You need to change the line in your code to the following

```
$("#idPerson").val(1).trigger('change');
```

See here for the more detailed example on [`How to Add, Select or Clear`](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items).