# How to set selected value of jquery select2 for more than 1 drop-downs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

My form contains 5 drop-down lists. I'm using `JQuery Select2` for each `drop-down list`. When I'm trying to edit it only one drop-down list shows previous set value.

**My code:**

```
$('.select2').select2({
  //placeholder: 'Select an option'
});

if (data.candidateId !== '') {
  $("#candidateParentId").select2().select2(data.candidateParentId, data.parent);
  $("#candidateTypeId").select2().select2(data.candidateTypeId, data.candidateType);
}
```

But this code shows only Candidate Parent Value and not Candidate Type value.

I'm getting both values in console.

I just refer to this:
[How to set selected value of jquery select2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187926/how-to-set-selected-value-of-jquery-select2/35131804)

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadtarawneah/o0uxjjtq/23/)

Comment: This link shows only for single drop-down list, need more than one drop-down on the same form.

Comment: $("#candidateParentId").select2().select2('val', data.candidateParentId);
$("#candidateTypeId").select2().select2('val',data.candidateTypeId);
Here you can try this. data.candidateParentId or data.candidateTypeId values are present in your dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$("#candidateParentId").select2("val", data.parent);

$("#candidateTypeId").select2("val", data.candidateType);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please format your code and add more details to the answer for other developers to understand what exactly you're trying to explain.