# Select 2 jquery set multiple values selected

Tags: jquery

I have used below code for set selected values into select2() but it not working when i am getting values dynamic from ajax. If a added static values then it is working fine. So help me about this.
Below i added my code in that first one working and second one not.

I got the values of `[response['pictoGramArr']` this from ajax is `"GHS02","GHS04"`

```
var arr = ["GHS04","GHS09"];
$("#ing_pictogram").select2("val", arr);

$("#ing_pictogram").select2("val", [response['pictoGramArr']]);
```

There is no any error in console, so why not working?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131804/863110) could help.

Comment: @Mosh Feu in this same problem as i faced working for static value but not for dynamic which i mentioned.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `response['pictoGramArr']` (you've included a value, but with a typo)? You're then putting it in an array, so would be the same as `$("#ing_pictogram").select2("val", [arr]);` - which probably then won't work either.  Try `$("#ing_pictogram").select2("val", response['pictoGramArr']);`