# Default selected option in select2 multiple select with remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I am trying to add the default selected option to multiple select2 with remote data. But the title is set instead of the option text. This is my code:

**Html**

```
<select class="form-control select_medicines" id="select_medicines" name="medicines[]" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($medicines as $medicine)
        <option value="{{$medicine->id}}" selected="selected">{{$medicine->fa_name . "(" . $medicine->en_name . ")"}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".select_medicines").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                search: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: $.map(data.data, function(obj) {
                    return {
                        id: obj.id,
                        fa_name: obj.fa_name,
                        en_name: obj.en_name,
                        is_for_diabetes: obj.is_for_diabetes
                    };
                }),
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 15) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: 'search',
    width: '100%',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) {
        return repo.text;
    }

    var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" ;

    markup += "<div class='mt-0 mb-2 text-dark'>";

    if (repo.is_for_diabetes === "1"){
        markup+= "<i class='mdi mdi-star mr-1'></i>";
    }

    markup += repo.fa_name + "(" + repo.en_name + ")";
    markup += "</div>";

    markup += "</div></div>";
    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.fa_name || repo.en_name;
}
});
```

and this is the result:
[image]

the title of option is set but text of option is empty. how can I set text of option? default selected options must be shown like "select after search"
[image]

I try to add value like {id: 12, text: metformin} to select but the default options were not selected and the remote data did not work for the options and only showed the data in Json instead of the remote data.

I did this as another solution but no option was selected.

**Controller**

```
$medicines_id = $user->medicines()->pluck('medicines.id')->all();
$medicines_fa_name = $user->medicines()->pluck('medicines.fa_name')->all();
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control select_medicines" id="select_medicines" name="medicines[]" multiple="multiple"></select>
@if(count($medicines_id) > 0)
    @foreach($medicines_id as $k => $medicine_id)
        <input value='{{json_encode("{id: $medicine_id, text: $medicines_fa_name[$k]}")}}' class="checked_medicines" readonly hidden>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

These lines were added to the JavaScript file.

**JS**

```
$('.checked_medicines').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var json  = JSON.parse(val);
    //json = {id: 12, text: گلی پیزاید}
    $(".select_medicines").select2('data',json);
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong but in your `processResult` you have not set `text` which will be display when any option is selected . i.e : Just add `text :  obj.fa_name +" :"+obj.en_name` in your json  here `return {  id: obj.id,..`

Comment: Thanks @Swati but that part is for after select. and after select is works right. my problem is for before select. before select I want to have default select option and that default selected options dose not have text and this is wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I tried the code you said, but it didn't work. @Swati

Comment: If you are loading *option* from ajax call ..then , why you have added them in dom by defaults ? Try removing them(your options inside select-box) completely and setting selected value after ajax call.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27964808/10606400) should be helpful.

Comment: I tried this code but no option was selected. In the HTML section, I deleted the lines related to foreach and added this line . if(count($medicines_id) > 0) foreach($medicines_id as $k => $medicine_id)<input value='{{json_encode("{id: $medicine_id, text: $medicines_fa_name[$k]}")}}' class="checked_medicines" readonly hidden> endforeach  endif. And I added this code in the JavaScript file. $('.checked_medicines').each(function () {var val = $(this).val();  var json=JSON.parse(val); //json = {id: 12, text: گلی پیزاید} $(".select_medicines").select2('data',json); }); @Swati

Comment: I edit my question and add these codes there

Comment: Use `trigger('change');` as well after setting value .

Comment: Thank you @Swati . This part worked right on a similar project. But in this project, again, after adding the code you mentioned, it set the title only for the selected options, and the text of the option was displayed blank again. My last code after the correction was as follows. `var $newOption = $("<option selected='selected'></option>").val("TheID").text("The text") $("#myMultipleSelect2").append($newOption).trigger('change');`

Comment: Still not sure why that doesn't work . If i try creating jsfiddle for this its working there just fine . Is this online somehere or you can replicate that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 4month I found my answer. the problem was in "formatRepoSelection" function for select 2. I must change it to

```
function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.fa_name || repo.en_name || repo.text;
}
```

I had deleted the "repo.text" code and the problem was that the label was not displayed. Now after adding this part, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand you well. Are you trying to store JSON data inside the value attribute of the option tag?

```
<select class="form-control select_medicines" id="select_medicines" name="medicines[]" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($medicines as $medicine)
        <option value='{{json_encode($medicine)}}' selected="selected">{{$medicine->fa_name . "(" . $medicine->en_name . ")"}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Be careful to use single quotes on the value attribute to avoid mixing it with the dobleqoutes of the JSON string

Comment: Hi @Chico3001 Thanks for the reply. But for the value of these choices must be medicine -> id. And this part works right. The problem is that the text of the option is not displayed correctly and only the title is set. I edited my question.  look at the second picture. default selected options must be like "select after search"